# Qt signals and slots working

Tags: qt

I have created a Main Window which consists of menu bar with the first menu being "file". Now I am trying to open another window if I click on the "file" menu item. But I am not getting the receiver object of the other window while designing. How can I establish a link?

I am using Qt 4.7

Comment: with just this information, nobody will be able to help you. Try to add some code that shows your problem. Best would be some code that is compilable by itself (with qt of course).

Comment: Maybe you could try to make a public slot function of the other another window object and connect it with your signal.

Comment: How are you instantiating the other object, or is just hidden?  Which signal are using on the menu?  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it by manual linking - this time you will have to write it yourself :P

Simply add a new slot to your window's class, add include for second's window header. Then in slot implementation create new window if necesary and simply call show on it.

Secondly you have to connect file meny to your signal - best is to add connect call in your window constructor AFTER intializing ui.

Also note that if your file option contains actually any submenu, then it's signal will never be emmited, so you need to think about something else in such case.